# How to change right single quotation marks to left ones?

Tags: microsoft-word, docx, microsoft-word-2019

I have a word document in which all the single quotation marks are *right* ones:

[image]

I must change all of them to *left single quotation marks*. I tried *Find & Replace* function but it didn't work. These both signs even look the same in the type field:

[image: Find & Replace]

When I press the *Replace all* button, it says around 7000 signs have been replaced but in reality nothing changes. I repeated this action a few times but no luck. It is for my mum's work and as she works at a publishing house, these kind of things do matter. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: What happens if you save the document after you do the search/replace, then reopen it? Also, it may actually replace the signs, but then automatically change them back. So what if you change them to something else, then change the other one too, then change them to what they should be?

Comment: I'm guessing those are all smart quotes rather than strict typographic entries. You'll have to switch off smart, then do the replace using correct data. The 'single quote' on your keyboard is a non-specific 'dumb' quote; you'll have to look up the correct glyph for that language. & btw, they're not really quotes, they're apostrophes.

Comment: @LPChip didn't work

Answer (score 2):

These steps are from Word 2016, but should work in more recent versions as well.  Start with your document open.  Open Word menu File->Options .  Click Proofing section on the left, then AutoCorrect options on the right, then the tab "AutoFormat as you type".  Uncheck 'Straight quotes' with “Smart quotes”.  Press OK and OK.

Make a new paragraph.  Type a sentence with some single and double quotes.  Compare to your existing smart ones.  Copy the desired character. 
 Open Find-Replace.  Paste into the Replace field.  Click into your document.  Find one of the problem characters and copy it.  Paste into the Find field.  Perform the replace all.

Note that this will change all of the original characters, so it may be better to go one by one.  I don't know the language you're using.

Review your document.  Because of the Options change, new text that you type into Word will use the straight quotes.  However, your old documents will need to be edited if you want to be consistent.

Comment: I had done it at first but as it turns out, we need these exactly smart quotes, not the straight ones. But thanks anyway

Comment: Apologies, I misread your question, I have corrected my answer.  If Word is still automatically correcting it, we can do something a little clumsy using 7Zip and NotePad++ instead.